# using Excel OnKey without overriding default key behavior

Tags: excel, vba

Using `Application.OnKey <key>, <procedure>`, I can cause Excel to run `<procedure>` whenever `<key>` is pressed.

What I'd like is for it to do whatever pressing `<key>` would have done by default, and *then* run `<procedure>`.  In other words, I don't want to use `OnKey` to override what a key does, I want to use it to *add* to what a key does.

#### Background Info:

I'm using a barcode scanner that acts just like a keyboard when it scans something, typing in the characters of the barcode, followed by a carriage return (char 13).  This carriage return does trigger Excel's `OnKey "~"` event.

Right now, I can scan a barcode, and it puts the barcode's value in the cell, then moves down to the next cell.  This is a good start.  What I want to do is have Excel run some code along with this, so that it puts the value in the cell, moves down a cell, then runs a procedure.

Comment: since you already have the cell selection change, could you put a macro in the SelectionChange  event and do what you need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just "rethrow" the carriage return using `SendKeys`, and let Excel deal with it as it sees fit? Admittedly, this is a kludge, but perhaps no more so than the rest of your code as you describe it! It would be the simplest and most readable solution -- if it works.

```
Sub PlainOldCarriageReturn()

    Application.EnableEvents = False ' So it won't trigger OnKey.
    Application.SendKeys "~", True ' Send a carriage return.
    DoEvents ' Process the carriage return.
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Back to normal

End Sub
```

Just put `PlainOldCarriageReturn` at the beginning of the procedure called by `OnKey`.

My cursory testing indicates that this does works, but you'll want to test it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you have to simulate the action in your own code.  If you want to OnKey on Enter, you could use code like this

```
Sub SEtup()

    Application.OnKey "~", "DoThis"

End Sub

Sub DoThis()

    'Simulate enter key
    If Application.MoveAfterReturn Then
        Select Case Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
            Case xlDown
                If ActiveCell.Row < ActiveCell.Parent.Rows.Count Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Case xlToLeft
                If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
                End If
            Case xlToRight
                If ActiveCell.Column < ActiveCell.Parent.Columns.Count Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                End If
            Case xlUp
                If ActiveCell.Row > 1 Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
                End If
        End Select
    End If

    'This is your code
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address

End Sub
```

Another option is to use a Worksheet event.  If the barcode output is predictable, you might be able to use a Worksheet_SelectionChange event.  For instance, if your barcode always outputs four numbers, and dash, and two numbers, you could

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value Like "####-##" Then
        'do stuff here
        Debug.Print Target.Address
    End If

End Sub
```

That assumes your MoveAfterReturnDirection is xlDown, but you could code for other eventualities.  In fact, if the output is predictable, you might just use the Worksheet_Change event to identify barcode input and run a procedure.